# How to recover the coefficients of a formal noncommutative power series from a twist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, power-series, hopf-algebras

This is a very half-baked question relating to something in my PhD research. I am trying to apply these ideas to a different situation, but this is a starter case that I am trying to think about. Therefore I'd like to try to set things up quite generally, although I think this is still incredibly vague. Apologies in advance!

Let's suppose I have some commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $A$ (think: subring of the complex numbers) and let $B = A[\alpha, \alpha^{-1}]$ for some element $\alpha$ (thought of as a complex number not in $A$).

Let $A\langle\langle x_0, x_1\rangle\rangle$ denote the ring of formal power series in noncommuting variables $x_0, x_1$ with coefficients in $A$. That is, let $X$ be the free monoid on $\left\{ x_0, x_1\right\}$. Then an element of $A\langle\langle x_0, x_1\rangle\rangle$ is a formal series
$$S = \sum_{w \in X}S_w w, \quad S_w\in A.$$

The ring $A\langle\langle x_0, x_1\rangle\rangle$ is a Hopf algebra with the coproduct for which $x_0$ and $x_1$ are primitive. Let $\text{GrL}(A\langle\langle x_0, x_1\rangle\rangle)$ denote the set of grouplike elements of this Hopf algebra.

I am interested in the following map: set $\alpha = 2\pi i$, and let $f: \text{GrL}(A\langle\langle x_0, x_1\rangle\rangle)\to \text{GrL}(B\langle\langle x_0, x_1\rangle\rangle)$ be the conjugation map

$$S\mapsto S \exp(2 \pi i x_1) S^{-1}=S(1+2\pi i x_1 + \frac{(2\pi i)^2}{2}x_1 x_1 + \dots)S^{-1}.$$

**Question**: I have heard that it is possible to recover the (space of) coefficients $S_w$ of $S$ from the "twisted series" $f(S)$. How can one go about doing this? Is it a direct computation or is there an abstract way to see it? I have heard that this is discussed in Deligne-Goncharov's paper *[Groupes fondamentaux motiviques de Tate mixte](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302267.pdf)* but unfortunately my French isn't very good and the exposition seems fairly complicated.

---

The motivation for this comes from what happens to the Drinfeld associator $S = \Phi(x_0, x_1)$ under monodromy around the punctured point $1\in\mathbb{P}^1\backslash\left\{0,1,\infty\right\}$. More abstractly (and unfortunately much less certainly in my mind), let $_{0}\Pi_{1}$ denote the (de Rham) torsor of paths from the tangential basepoint $\vec{1}_0$ at $0$ to the tangential basepoint $-\vec{1}_1$ at $1$. I believe that we have $_{0}\Pi_{1}\cong \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}\langle x_0, x_1\rangle)$, the spectrum of the shuffle algebra. (I am actually unsure on whether this is correct because $_{0}\Pi_{1}$ is a torsor under the de Rham fundamental group - which is also this same scheme - but it is only isomorphic after picking a point. Perhaps this isomorphism above is not natural?)

Set $_{0}\Pi_0$ (resp. $_1\Pi_1$) to be the de Rham fundamental group at the tangential basepoint $\vec{1}_0$ (resp. $-\vec{1}_1$). Then for $K$ a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, the $K$-points of each of these schemes $_a\Pi_b$ should be

$$_a\Pi_b (K) \cong \text{GrL}(K\langle\langle x_0, x_1\rangle\rangle),$$

although these isomorphisms may be different in each case. The Drinfeld associator lives in $_0\Pi_1 (\mathbb{R})\hookrightarrow _0\Pi_1 (\mathbb{C})$, and can be thought of as the "straight line path" $\text{dch}$ from $\vec{1}_0$ to $-\vec{1}_1$. Then by picking the element $\exp(2\pi i x_1)\in _1\Pi_1 (\mathbb{C})$ (thought of as a small loop around the puncture at $1$) we first go along $\text{dch}$, then go around the loop around $1$, and then go along the reverse path $\text{dch}^{-1}$. This results in a map

$$_0\Pi_1 (\mathbb{C}) \to  _{0}\Pi_0 (\mathbb{C}), \quad S\mapsto S \exp(2\pi i x_1) S^{-1}.$$

The idea is that one should be able to recover the original "path" from $\vec{1}_0$ to $-\vec{1}_1$ from this new "loop". I am trying to understand this case before moving onto a much more complicated twisting map arising from the case of a punctured elliptic curve.

Comment: Do you think it would be better/also beneficial to post this question in MathOverflow? As I understand things, that setting might bear more fruit for a research-related question like this.

Comment: And if you're needing to read math in French, here's a great set of links and answers for algebraic geometry (including motives and all things Deligne/Grothendieck, Serre, etc.) in particular: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117622/math-french-words

Comment: Also possibly check out Milne's PDF on motives: http://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/mot.html

Comment: Dear @TannerStrunk, thank you for these helpful comments! It's great to have a set of links for French algebraic geometry. Thanks for the advice about posting on MO as well. I will have a think about how to reformulate the question to make it more suitable there and then I will probably repost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. You recover $S$ only up to right multiplication by a$$\text{exp}(\text{multiple of }e_1).$$The point is that the Hopf algebra—with a grain of salt: completed tensor product needed—is the universal enveloping algebra of the free Lie algebra in $x_1$ and $x_2$, and that in this Lie algebra, the centralizer of $x_1$ is reduced to the multiples of $x_1$.

Model: In a group $G$, given $x$ with centralizer $Z(x)$, the conjugate $gxg^{-1}$ determines $g$ up to right multiplication by a $z$ in $Z(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer - this is very helpful! Before I accept it, would you be able to provide either some more details or a reference as to how you recover the coset $g Z(x)$ from $g x g^{-1}$? I'm sure this is standard group theory but I would like to see how it is done.

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid and confusing myself but I understand now what you mean by "up to a right multiple of $Z(x)$": from $b=g x g^{-1}$ we uniquely recover $g$ as $g = b g x^{-1}$, but if $g$ were replaced by $g h$ for any $h\in Z(x)$ we would only be able to recover $g$ and not $gh$ from $b = (gh)x(gh)^{-1}$ via this process.